# Adding an event handler to a specific children within a DOM tree that is created on runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I'm trying to bind an event handler to an element that is a children in a DOM tree that is added to the HTML dynamic while runtime. The following HTML shows what I got. The table and its thead and tbody are static HTML. Later I'm adding the content of tbody (`<tr><td><img src="bla.png"></td></tr>`) to it.

```
<table id="progData">
    <thead>
        <th>Image</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><img src="bla.png"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So now I want to bind an event handler on the image like:

```
$("#progData").on("click", "img", function(e){/*do sth in here*/});
```

But this doesnt work for some reason. I have to use

```
$("#progData").on("click", "tr", function(e){/*do sth in here*/});
```

to get it to work at least when clicking on the row.

Is there any way to bind the event to a dynamic element that is deeper in the DOM than the direct child element?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you apply the first approach?

Comment: Looks fine to me once the broken HTML is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/98aKQ/

Comment: Why the HTML is broken? Seems to be correct for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I'm sorry. I had a mistake within my callback function in the event handler. As I had to work with "tr" before I accessed some attributes that are only present within the "tr". So as I changed the handler to the "img" object I just forgot to access the attributes now by parent() functions... :/

So it was just my mistake. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing  -

```
$("#progData").find("img").on("click", function(e){/*do sth in here*/});
```

If the HTML is already loaded before the code is hit.

OR

You could try adding a class to the dynamic content and then bind on its click event such as

HTML -

```
<tr><td><img class="jMyImage" src="bla.png"></td></tr>
```

Javascript -

```
$(".jMyImage").on("click", function(e){/*do sth in here*/});
```

Comment: The OP wants to use event bubbling to attach the click. Your approach requires the image to be there.

Comment: It still will have the same exact problem.

Comment: Not if if we know when the code is hit.
Whenever I implement some code where I have to load content dynamically, I raise an event in my code, which notifies an observer, which in turn binds to events on the dynamically added content. Would work in this case.

Comment: TH OP Was using event bubbling so they do not have to add events everytime something is added. Sad thing is the OP responded and it was another bug in the code...

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are after if I understand correctly:

```
$(document).on("click", "#progData img", function(e){/*do sth in here*/});
```

or if you want just the first one:

```
$(document).on("click", "#progData img:nth-child(2)", function(e){/*do sth in here*/});
```

Because the element is added dynamically you need to attach to the document as the element isn't created yet or is created after the document is. More info can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: If the second one works, there is no issue with the id not being there.

Comment: @epascarello the issue is with the image not being there, to make it clearer it now looks for the second one. To be more specific you could just make it "#progData tbody img"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are trying to attach events to a tag which is still not there. I mean, you should check the moment where you add the event listener to be after the moment where the table row is inserted. For example this works for me:

```
var onImageLoaded = function() {
    $("#progData").on("click", "img", function(e){
        if(e.currentTarget.tagName == 'IMG') {
            console.log("clicked");
        }
    })
}

var table = $("#progData");
table.find("tbody").html("<tr><td><img src=\"http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/articles/CSSThePowerOfInherit/icon-bullet.jpg\" onload=\"javascript:onImageLoaded();\"></td></tr>");
```

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/ybavx/